# feedback loop for results from elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a scenario where I need to list a bunch of jobs from elastic search. The searches would mainly be done by keywords eg. (electrical  engineering, driver etc.) I want to create a feedback system where corresponding keyword is given higher weightage if the user clicks on a particular job.

So far it is all doable. I am facing problem because in my system user can search with multiple keywords eg. (driver or electrical engineering). Query that would be constructed for this would be as follows

```
{
  "query" : {
      "bool": {
        "should": [
           {
               "multi_match": {
                  "query" : "electrical engineering",
                  "fields" : [
                    "description^1.0",
                    "name^1.0"
                  ]
               }
           },
           {
            "multi_match": {
                  "query" : "driver",
                  "fields" : [
                    "description^1.0",
                    "name^1.0"
                  ]
               }   
           }
        ]
      }
  },
  "sort" : [
    {
      "_score" : {
        "order" : "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Now in this scenario, is there a way, I can associate a result with a particular multi match clause, so that i can identify that this result is here because of word ***driver*** and this is here because of ***electrical engineering***.

If anyone has any better idea so that i can complete my feedback loop, please feel free share it.

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for highlighting capabilities? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-highlighting.html Or maybe explain capabilities? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-explain.html

Comment: no, i was looking at creating a popularity for a particular job corresponding to a particular keyword. In certain scenario one job would be listed for more than one keyword, but for a certain keyword it would be popular eg. if job is "electrical engineering for microchip driver", then this would be popular for electrical keyword but not driver keyword. Depending on the user clicks i want to feed info back into system

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my problem in elasticsearch forums, posting the same here to help anyone else.

Elastic search provides the concept of named queries , these can be used to give names to each query that is applied, as part of the result , ES would list all the queries that matched. For eg. the above query can be written like this

```
{
  "query" : {
      "bool": {
        "should": [
           {
               "multi_match": {
                  "query" : "electrical engineering",
                  "fields" : [
                    "description^1.0",
                    "name^1.0"
                  ],
                  "_name" : "firstQuery"
               }
           },
           {
            "multi_match": {
                  "query" : "driver",
                  "fields" : [
                    "description^1.0",
                    "name^1.0"
                  ],
                  "_name" : "secondQuery"
               }   
           }
        ]
      }
  },
  "sort" : [
    {
      "_score" : {
        "order" : "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

this would return results with **matched queries**